# Is the function $A\cos(\lambda x) + B\sin(\lambda x)$ periodical?

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, periodic-functions

I am trying to check the function for periodicity...

$y(x) = A\cos(\lambda x) + B\sin(\lambda x) $

I think that it's possible to rewrite the function as $y(x) = Csin (\lambda x + t)$,
where $C = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$

But I can't prove that new function is periodical or is not periodical.

How can I do it?

Comment: Study $y(x+T)$.

Comment: **Hint**: $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ have the period $2\pi$.

Comment: Yes, but you're running down the wrong road. Instead you should try to rewrite $C\sin(\lambda x+t)$ using trigonometric identities and make it match $A\cos(\lambda x)+B\sin(\lambda x)$. It just being periodic is not enough to show that the functions are the same (but if you show them being the same it's obvious that it would be periodic).

Comment: Thank you, but I have difficulties anyway... I have sum of two periodical functions $A \cos (\lambda x)$ and $B \sin(\lambda x)$ . How can I use it for my solve?

Comment: @skyking: your comment is misleading/ambiguous. You can show periodicity in both representations.

Comment: @NikolaiPaukov: in what way having a sum of peridical functions is a problem ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Perhaps I misunderstood him, but if he's aiming for showing that the function can be written $C\sin(\lambda x+t)$ you have to show that anyway. Showing that $y$ is periodic will not bring you any closer that goal, actually that part is not required for that goal.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you want to show that you have to show that. As I said I perhaps misunderstood him about his intent, but if I understood him correctly then yes you do. Showing that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are periodic is **not** sufficient to show that $f(x)=g(x)$, even if they do have the same period.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, it was $A\cos(\lambda x)+B\cos(\lambda x) = C\sin(\lambda x+t)$. **If** that's what he wants to prove then that is precisely what he ought to do.

Comment: @skyking: do I read the title wrongly ? And the first sentence ? And the fourth ?

Comment: I just need to prove that function $y(x) = A\cos(\lambda x) + B\sin(\lambda x)$ is periodical...

Comment: @YvesDaoust Probably not. As I pointed out I probably misunderstood him. I read also the second sentence and got the impression that hes actual goal was to prove that we could write $y(x)=C\sin(\lambda x + t)$. I hope you're aware that XY-questions occur here. Now that he has clarified that he only want to prove that $y(x)$ is periodic I think we have settled this. I misunderstood him, that's all - apart from that the rest is just consequences of that (assuming my original understanding there's nothing wrong in my comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The period of the sine and cosine functions are well known to be $2\pi$ for both. Hence $\dfrac{2\pi}\lambda$ is a period of the linear combination, for the argument $\lambda x$.

Remains to show that it is the smallest.

---

Setting $t:=\lambda x$, let $T=\lambda X$ be the period.

$$A\cos(t+T)+B\sin(t+T)=A\cos(t)+B\sin(t)$$

implies, using the sum-to-product formula,

$$-2A\sin\left(t+\frac T2\right)\sin\left(\frac T2\right)+2A\cos\left(t+\frac T2\right)\sin\left(\frac T2\right)=0.$$

This expression is identically zero for the smallest nonzero value $T=2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=A\cos(\lambda x) + B\sin(\lambda x)$$
Suppose we have $$f(x+p)=f(x)$$ for all $x$, so we have also for $x=0$:

$$A\cos(\lambda p) + B\sin(\lambda p)= A\cos(0) + B\sin(0) =A$$ So if we take $\lambda p = 2\pi $ we get $p={2\pi\over \lambda}$ which is period since it is not difficult to see that $f(x+p)-f(x)=...=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to prove that $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ is least period? How did you guess to get $p = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} $ as period?

Comment: 1. Yes it is, since $2\pi$ is least period for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.                 
2. We know that $2\pi$ is period for these two function so I put $\lambda p = 2\pi$.

Comment: @JohnWatson: this argument is insufficient. Think of the functions $\cos 10x-\cos x$ and $\cos 10x+\cos x$. Both have period $2\pi$ but their sum has period $\pi/5$.